# Loop that displays a table

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am new to programming and am having a hard time creating a program that displays data collected from an array within a for loop into a table. I am able to collect the data, but am unable to store it and display it afterwards. Any thoughts?

This is what I have written

```
import java.util.Scanner;

//Fahrenheit to Celsius converter

public class CelsiusConversion 
{

    public static void Celsius(String[] args) 
    {//Open method 1

        int num;
        double [] temps;
        double fahrenheit;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the amount of numbers you wish to average: ");
        num = input.nextInt();

        while (num<1)
        {
            System.out.println("You did not enter a number greater than zero. Please enter a number greater than zero:");
            num = input.nextInt();
        }

        temps = new double [num];

        for (int t = 0; t <num; t++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter temperature " + (t+1) + " in Fahrenheit:");
            temps[t] = input.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("Please confirm the temperature in Fahrenheit");
            fahrenheit = input.nextDouble();

            double celsius = 5.0/9*(fahrenheit - 32);

            System.out.println( fahrenheit + " in Celsius is " + celsius + ".");

        }

    }//Close method 1


}
```

Comment: I would like the data to be displayed outside of the for loop if possible

Comment: Post the code of what you have already tried. And please put it on the question as an edit not on the comments.

Comment: Please provide a code sample and explain in detail what is not working, that do you want and errors you got

Comment: What kind of table? `JTable`? An `html` table?

Answer (score 0):

Without any sample code it's hard to give advice, but here's an intrigue and a suggestion:

I noticed you included the tag 'arrays', do you completely understand arrays? Are you using an Array? If you are make sure that you're initializing a different part of your array every iteration of the loop (This is called 'walking through' an array). If you don't do this your array will only hold the last value you enter into the array on the last iteration of the loop.

Also, it's a little finnicky to display an array directly with `System.out`. Instead you can make a string by walking through the array again, or you can use `Arrays.toString(array)`.

For example, the first code displays `1, 2, 3, 4`. The next code displays `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

```
int[] num = {1, 2, 3, 4};

String print = "";

for (int hold : num)
{
     print += hold + ", ";
} 

System.out.println(print + "\b\b");
```

Next code

```
int[] num = {1, 2, 3, 4};

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num));
```